# dropdown pre-select without fireing onchange

Tags: semantic-ui

this is preselectiong my `.item.active.selected` but unfortunately it also fires the `onChange`. Is there another way?

```
$(function() {
  $.each($(".ui.dropdown"), function(i, dropdown) {
    selected_value = $(dropdown).find(".item.selected").data("value");
    $(dropdown).dropdown("set selected", selected_value);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can set value and text instead.

So,

```
$(function() {
  $.each($(".ui.dropdown"), function(i, dropdown) {
    var val = $(dropdown).find(".item.active").data("value");
    var text = $(dropdown).find(".item.active").html();

    $(dropdown)
        .dropdown("set value", val)
        .dropdown("set text", text);
  });

});
```

But why do that?

You can pre-select a value by:

1. Setting a value in `<input type="hidden" value="my_val" />` field in div-based dropdowns
2. Adding `selected` attribute to the `option` for select-based dropdowns

Comment: i didnt knew about the hidden field. but using ".selected" is NOT changing the display text of the dropdown. thats what i care about.

Comment: My bad! that should be `.item.active`. Not `selected`. Gonna change the code now

Comment: but i give them ".active.selected" - and the display text is still not changed. so thats why i came up with my own idea of initialize it ?!

Comment: well, active makes it bold and selected makes it with background - obviously i use the class .item. ill try again and let you know

Comment: its not working.... heres my code. http://pastie.org/10612954 supposed to show the first list item, as display text. but it doesnt. it just shows "Kommentare filtern" all the time

Comment: `set text` wont fire the change-callback. thats what i needed. thanks mate. now i saw it!